# New lines in MVC partial view causing problems in firefox 5.0 / jQuery 1.6.2

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple table that is rendered in an MVC partial view and returned to the client via a jQuery ajax call.

Here's what a simplified version of what the success callback looks like:

```
function (html, status, xhr)
{
 html = $(html); //Get html table as a jQuery object
 var tblClass = html.attr("class");
}
```

Now in IE9 I get get the table class no problem. In FF5 it fails. I debugged in Firebug and found that there is a "\r\n" before the `<table>` tag in the html string being returned. This isn't really surprising because there is a blank line above the `<table>` tag in my partial view for readability.

When  `html = $(html);` is run, instead of getting a jQuery object w/ a single table element in it I found that I have 2 elements in the jQuery object.

Element [0] shows up in FireBug as:

```
<TextNode textContent=";\n">
```

Element [1] is my table and this is causing the problem. What I would expect is what I'm getting in IE9 which is a jQuery object only containing a single element (the table). I don't know why whitespace is being converted into `<TextNode textContent=";\n">`

Here's my view:

```
@model IDataPage<EssenceNet.Domain.Transforms.EssenceResult>

<table class="csGrid">
    <tr>
        <th data-sort="Name" class='a' style="min-width:50px"><a></a>Name</th>
        <th data-sort="EssenceTypeID" style="min-width:50px"><a></a>Type</th>
        <th style="width:100%">Description</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var r in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr data-id="@r.EssenceID">
            <td style="color:#265E15">@r.Name</td>
            <td>@r.Type</td>
            <td>@r.Description.MaxLength(100)</td>
        </tr>
    }
    @Html.WritePagerRow(Model);
</table>
```

And here's the ajax call (I've tried it several different ways) all w/ the same results:

```
$.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                returnType: 'html',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType:'application/json',
                success: successFunc
            });
```

Any ideas why this is happening and what to do about it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the semi-colon after:

```
@Html.WritePagerRow(Model);
```

If you look closely in Visual Studio, you'll see that the semi-colon doesn't have a light gray background but a white one. That means it is regarded as HTML code, not as C# code.

Remove the semi-colon and your problem will be gone.

Comment: Ah, you're right! The fact that the text node was appearing as the element before the table in the jQuery object made me think it was before the table in the string as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

make sure while making ajax request `dataType=html`

or

you may do `$(html).find('TextNode').remove().end()`

or

**show us ur view and ajax options**

**Edit 1**

in this line `@Html.WritePagerRow(Model);` , try removing semicolon

**Edit 2**

I thing i would like to suggest, while using ajax when you get some unexpected result the best thing is to do is

a> look ur response in firebug(which most ppl usually do)

b> Also see ur response by typing url directly into browser. (this solves many problems)

Comment: After jQuery 1.4 dataType isn't really needed. It figures it out on its own based on content type but I've tried specifying 'html' as the datatype.

Comment: @Cj: i know that, but i said that just for try!!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say that whitespace is the issue, but more likely the `;` character before the new line?

Comment: No, the original html string contains no `;`. It has a `\r\n`. The `;` is something that happens after trying to convert the string into a jQuery object

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the return in a  and turn the whole thing into a jQuery object.